# Node + Github webhook for user activities

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, github-api

I will explain my problem easily:

I want to interact with the github webhooks to fetch when my user (or a logged user) click star on a repo (should be this [hook event](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/types/#watchevent)).

I have a simply server with node + express but I really don't understand how perform this. Could someone help me?

```
const chalk = require('chalk');
const express = require('express');
const serverConfig = require('./config/server.config');

const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || serverConfig.port;

console.log(chalk.bgGreen(chalk.black('###   Starting server...   ###'))); // eslint-disable-line

app.listen(port, () => {
  const uri = `http://localhost:${port}`;
  console.log(chalk.red(`> Listening ${chalk.white(serverConfig.env)} server at: ${chalk.bgRed(chalk.white(uri))}`)); // eslint-disable-line
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick test for this would be to use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to make a local port available from the outside :

```
ngrok http 8080
```

Then create the hook using the API using the `url` given by ngrok and your personal access token. You can also build the webhook manually in your repo hook section https://github.com/$USER/$REPO/settings/hooks/ (selecting `watch` events) :

```
curl "https://api.github.com/repos/bertrandmartel/speed-test-lib/hooks" \
     -H "Authorization: Token YOUR_TOKEN" \
     -d @- << EOF
{
  "name": "web",
  "active": true,
  "events": [
    "watch"
  ],
  "config": {
    "url": "http://e5ee97d2.ngrok.io/webhook",
    "content_type": "json"
  }
}
EOF
```

launch an http server listening on the port exposed with the `POST` endpoint you have specified :

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const port = 8080;

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.post('/webhook', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
    res.sendStatus(200);
})

app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('listening on port ' + port)
})
```

launch it :

```
node server.js
```

The server will now receive starring events

For debugging you can see the sent requests from Github in the hooks section :

```
https://github.com/$USER/$REPO/settings/hooks/
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Bertrand Martel, but this lock the hook to a repo, right? I want to "hook" my user activity. When I star a random repo I want trigger the hook

Comment: From the api [webhook page](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/) : "Each webhook can be installed on an organization or a specific repository", so I don't think there is such a feature available for individual user events. Even [PubSubHubbub](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/hooks/#pubsubhubbub) server subscribing only process repo events

Comment: So, basically, I can't monitoring what my user does right? What about if I transform my user into an organization?

Comment: organization can't star repo/follow user AFAIK, you can still poll [user events api](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/#list-public-events-performed-by-a-user)